# Add .attr to button not working when called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr

Not sure if I formatted the question right.  Have manually added the "data-next" and it is changing at the appropriate time, but still not changing. Have narrowed it down to the "showNext" function.

My objective is to iterate through the questions about the car the based on the number of cars the user enters.  I was thinking a loop at first, but this seemed to be a cleaner way to do it.  I'm new so I could be way off.

My problem is that while it does iterate through the correct number of times, and chrome shows that it is choosing that button as the "this" variable as I want it to, for some reason it is not adding the attribute.  That line of code fires, I get no errors, but nothing happens.

I have tried using the exact id of the button, defining "this" as a variable (ie: var el =  id of button) and a few other things I can't remember right now.  Nothing has worked. Also I have used the same type of command in other areas and it worked just fine.

The rest of the code works fine and it does cycle through the correct number of times, but it will not add the attr.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If I have left anything out, please let me know.  Thanks!

Here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 // hide all 'hideFirst' elements, except the first one:
$('.hideFirst:not(:first)').hide();

// Method used to show/hide elements :
function showNext(el) {
    // check if element has a 'data-next' attribute:
    if (el.data('next')) {
        // hide all elements with 'hideFirst' class:
        $('.hideFirst').hide();
        // show 'Back' button:
        $('#backButton').show();
        // show the element which id has been stored in 'data-next' attribute:
        $(el.data('next')).show();
        // push the parent element ('.hideFirst') into path array:
        path.push(el.closest('.hideFirst'));
    }
}

    //Logs the number of cars in the household
$("#carAmount").click(function () {
    numberOfCars = parseInt(document.getElementById("vehicleAmount").value);
    showNext($(this));
});

//allow user to chose the type of car they drive
$("#carType").change(function () {

    carChoice = $("#carType").val();
    $("#carType").attr("data-next", "#" + carChoice);
    showNext($(this));

});

//Decides whether the user has more cars to ask about
    $(".carBtn").click(function () {
        carCount++;
        //asks about other cars
        if (carCount < numberOfCars) {
            $(this).attr('data-next', '#vehicleType');
            $('#carType').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
        }
            //moves on to the next category
        else {
            $(this).attr('data-next', '#transportation');
        }
        showNext($(this));
    });
});
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div>
<form>
                <div class="hideFirst" id="vehicleCount">
                <label for="vehicleAmount">How many vehicles are there in your household?</label>
                <input type="text" id="vehicleAmount" />
                <button type="button" id="carAmount" data-next="#vehicleType" class="my-btn btnFoot"><i class="icon-footprint-right-d"></i></button>
            </div>

            <div class="hideFirst" id="vehicleType">
                <label for="carType">What kind of car do you drive?</label>
                <select id="carType">
                    <option disabled selected>--Choose One--</option>
                    <option value="gas">Gasoline</option>
                    <option value="diesel">Diesel</option>
                    <option value="cng">Natural gas</option>
                    <option value="hybrid">Hybrid</option>
                    <option value="elec">Electric</option>
                    <option value="hydrogen">Fuel Cell/Hydrogen</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="hideFirst" id="gas">
                <label for="fuelType">What type of fuel do you normally use??</label>
                <select id="gasType">
                    <option disabled selected>--Choose One--</option>
                    <option value="e10">e10 (regular unleaded)</option>
                    <option value="e85">e85</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="hideFirst" id="diesel">
                <label for="carType">What type of diesel fuel do you normally use?</label>
                <select id="dieselType" name="heatSource">
                    <option disabled selected>--Choose One--</option>
                    <option value="num5">Regular Diesel</option>
                    <option value="b10">B10 Biodiesel</option>
                    <option value="b100">B100 Biodiesel</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="hideFirst" id="cng">
                <label for="carCng">How much natural gas do you put in your car every month?</label>
                <input type="text" id="carCng" />
                <button type="button" id="propaneBill" class="carBtn btnFoot"><i class="icon-footprint-right-d"></i></button>
            </div>

            <div class="hideFirst" id="hybrid">
                <label for="carType">What kind of car do you drive?</label>
                <select id="carType" name="heatSource">
                    <option disabled selected>--Choose One--</option>
                    <option value="gas">Gasoline</option>
                    <option value="diesel">Diesel</option>
                    <option value="cng">Natural gas</option>
                    <option value="hybrid">Hybrid</option>
                    <option value="elec">Electric</option>
                    <option value="hydrogen">Fuel Cell/Hydrogen</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="hideFirst" id="elec">
                <label for="carElec">How many miles do you drive every month?</label>
                <input type="text" id="carElec" />
                <button type="button" id="elecMiles" class="carBtn btnFoot"><i class="icon-footprint-right-d"></i></button>
            </div>

            <div class="hideFirst" id="hydrogen">
                <h2>Good for you, you produce no negative Co2 emission with your vehicle!</h2>
                <button type="button" id="carsnow" class="carBtn btnFoot"><i class="icon-footprint-right-d"></i></button>
            </div>

            <div class="hideFirst" id="transportation">
                <h2>Why won't I display?</h2>
                <button type="button" data-next="" class="my-btn btnFoot"><i class="icon-footprint-right-d"></i></button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div>
            <button id="backButton">Back</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hoping to find some help here

Comment: You can replace your massive ifelse with just `$("#carType").attr("data-next", "#"+carChoice);`

Comment: Fair enough.  Still learning where I can shorten things.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it took a couple of days, but I figured this out.

The main problem is that the jquery .data- attributes are only read the very first time the property is accessed.  So while I was changing them, at the right time, they weren't being read. It was also the reason that, while the back button worked it would not allow you to go to different divs when going back through the questions.

Here is the line from the jQuery documentation:

> "The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is
>   accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values
>   are then stored internally in jQuery)."

[Link to the page](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

By changing the .data- to a combination of .attr and .prop depending on the necessary functionality I was able to get it working.

As I mentioned in my original question, I'm very new so if I didn't provide enough info, please let me know.

Here is the code for it to work properly and a [link to a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tlhull1/ja7qLzku/1/).

```js
  var carCount = 0;

  $(document).ready(function () {

      // hide all 'hideFirst' elements, except the first one:
      $('.hideFirst:not(:first)').hide();

      var visited = [];

      // Method used to show/hide elements :
      function showNext(el) {
          // check if element has a 'nextitem' attribute:
          if (el.attr('nextitem')) {
              // hide all elements with 'hideFirst' class:
              $('.hideFirst').hide();
              // show 'Back' button:
              $('#backButton').show();
              // show the element which id has been stored in 'nextitem' attribute:
              $(el.attr('nextitem')).show();
              // Push the parent element ('.hideFirst') into visited array:
              visited.push(el.closest('.hideFirst'));
          }
      }
          // click event for 'back' button:
    $('#backButton').click(function () {
        // hide all elements with 'hideFirst' class:
        $('.hideFirst').hide();
        // remove the last '.hideFirst' element from 'visited' array and show() it:
        visited.pop().show();
        // hide 'back' button if visited array is empty:
        visited.length || $(this).hide();
    }).hide(); // hide 'back' button on init

      $(".myBtn").click(function () {
          showNext($(this));
      });

      $("#amount").click(function () {
          numberOfCars = parseInt(document.getElementById("inputNumber").value);
          showNext($(this));
      });


      $("#typeA").change(function () {

          carChoice = $("#typeA").val();
          $("#typeA").attr("nextitem", "#" + carChoice);
          showNext($(this));
        //clears previous choices
          $('#typeA').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
          $('#typeB').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
          $('#typeC').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
      });

      //Decides how many more times to iterate through
      $(".carBtn").click(function () {
          carCount++;
          //asks about other cars
          if (carCount < numberOfCars) {
              $(this).attr('nextitem', '#main');
              $("#bar").html(carCount);
              $("#foo").html(numberOfCars);
          }
          //moves on to the next category
          else {
              $(this).attr('nextitem', '#last');
              $("#bar").html(carCount);
          }
          showNext($(this));
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <form>
        <div class="hideFirst">
            <label for="inputNumber">Number of times to iterate through</label>
            <input type="text" id="inputNumber" />
            <button type="button" nextitem="#main" class="myBtn" id="amount">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div class="hideFirst" id="main">
            <select id="typeA">
                <option disabled selected>--Choose One--</option>
                <option value="b">Option B</option>
                <option value="c">Option C</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="hideFirst" id="b">
            <label for="typeB">Type B</label>
            <select id="typeB">
                <option disabled selected>--Choose One--</option>
                <option value="a">Option a</option>
                <option value="b">Option b</option>
                <option value="c">Option c</option>
            </select>
            <button type="button" class="carBtn">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div class="hideFirst" id="c">
            <label for="typeC">Type C</label>
            <select id="typeC">
                <option disabled selected></option>
                <option value="a">Option a</option>
                <option value="b">Option b</option>
                <option value="c">Option c</option>
            </select>
            <button type="button" class="carBtn">Next</button>
        </div>
        <div class="hideFirst" id="last">
            <p>Done</p>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div>
        <br/>
        <button id="backButton">Back</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Number of times you asked for:<span id="foo"></span>
        </p>
        <p>Number of times around this form:<span id="bar"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
```